# Failure to add opacity transition via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Essentially my ultimate goal was to get a fading text effect from left to right, and after a few days of trial and error I ended up here.

The function is supposed to grab all divs determined by class name, loops through the divs, and per each div assign the text out of it to a string, then iterate over each character in the string and apply opacity transition effects. I was trying to get it to work so I could tell if the transition would happen concurrent with for loop iterations, or does the loop wait until the transition is complete before going to the next character, which wouldnt get it to where I want. If somehow thats the case I was thinking of maybe a recursive algorithm if its possible javascript (have the loop go to the next character and begin transitioning when the 1st transition reached a certain percent so the original transition triggers the next etc etc)

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> .text{opacity: 0;} </style>
<script> 
function fadeDivs(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("text"); 
    for(i=0; i<divs.length(); i++){
        var string = divs[i].text();
        for(j=0; j<string.length(); j++){
            var letter = string.charAt(j);
            letter.style.transition = "opacity 1s ease 0s";
            letter.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="fadeDivs()">
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated attempt: Will go from 1 to 0, but not 0 to 1.

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.text{opacity:1;}
}</style>
<script> 
function fadeDiv(string) {
    $(string).each(function() {
        var str = $(this).html();
        str = str.trim().split("");
        var newDiv = "";
        for (var i = 0, end = str.length; i < end; i++) {
            newDiv += '<span>' + str[i] + '</span>';}
        $(this).html(newDiv);
    });
}
$('document').ready(function() {
    var str= $('.text');
    fadeDiv(str);
    $("span").each(function(i) {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},i*15);
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from basic Javascript errors, the main problem is that css cannot be applied on each individual character in an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based off the update above I ended up here, and it works perfectly. Thanks for everyone's efforts and inputs.

What this does is take all divs with the text class, and create a new string of characters wrapped in span tags in order to hide them individually and allow for a incremented fade in effect

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
span{display: none;}
}</style>
<script> 
function fadeDiv(string) {
    $(string).each(function() {
        var str = $(this).html();
        str = str.trim().split("");
        var newDiv = "";
        for (var i = 0, end = str.length; i < end; i++) {
            newDiv += '<span>' + str[i] + '</span>';}
        $(this).html(newDiv);
    });
}
$('document').ready(function() {
    var str = $('.text');
    fadeDiv(str);
    $("span").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i*50).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** your code have some error:

use `divs.length` not `divs.length();` & `string.length` not `string.length();`

because length is the `property` not `method`.

use `var string = divs[i].innerHTML;` instead of `var string = divs[i].text();`

but you should not go that far use simply:

```
function fadeDivs(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("text"); 
    for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
        var string = divs[i];
        string.style.transition = "opacity 1s ease 0s";
        string.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Knapp try the modified fadeDivs().

Answer (score 1):

There are basic Javascript problems in your code along with your mixing of jQuery code with Javascript.

But that aside, you just can't do what you are trying to do that way. CSS styles cannot be applied per character basis for an element. CSS styles are applied to an entire element. So, that premise of your code itself is wrong.

You can do two things to achieve what you want.

1. Either wrap every character in a `span` of its own and then use JS to change `opacity` on all one by one.
2. Use CSS3 animations to get that effect.

Here is one crude example of using CSS3 animation:

```css
.text {
    position: relative; width: 320px; height: 32px;
    -webkit-animation: fade 10s; animation: fade 10s;
}

.text::after {
    content:''; position: absolute; 
    height: 100%; background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: slide 10s; animation: slide 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% { left: 0; width: 100%; }
    100% { left: 100%; width: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% { left: 0; width: 100%; }
    100% { left: 100%; width: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
<div class="text"> this text should appear from left to right </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To animate each letter's opacity you would have to put all letters in a `span` element, which is not very efficient if you have a large amount of text. I prefer defining an `svg` `linearGradient`, `mask` the text and use JavaScript to animate the `x1` and `x2` values, which will give you exactly what you are trying to achieve.

**Note:** The CSS `mask` property doesn't work on Chrome, checkout the workaround for Chrome below.

```js
var grad = document.getElementById('gradient');
var animSpeed = 70;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var anim = setTimeout(function() {
    var x1 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x1').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
    var x2 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x2').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
    grad.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    grad.setAttribute('x2', x2);
  }, animSpeed * i);
}
```

```css
.text {
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">This text should appear from left to right</div>
<div class="text">This text should appear from left to right</div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="-15%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

---

### Workaround for Chrome

The idea is not to use the CSS `mask` property. To do that, I've removed the `div`s and added the `svg` `text` elements and applied the `mask` in the HTML itself.

```js
var grad = document.getElementById('gradient');
var animSpeed = 25;

for (i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
  var anim = setTimeout(function() {
    var x1 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x1').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
    var x2 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x2').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
    grad.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    grad.setAttribute('x2', x2);
  }, animSpeed * i)
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="-15%" y1="0%" x2="5%" y2="0%">
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text x="2" y="12" mask="url(#mask)">This text should appear from left to right</text>
  <text x="2" y="27" mask="url(#mask)">This text should appear from left to right</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I was liking this solution, but there were some issues, I didnt understand everything too well So I cant really manipulate it to my own needs and just copying and pasting is bad form to me, im trying to learn not just use someone elses work. I ended up adding span tag to all my chars and iterate over each and applying a animate function, my only issue is I can change opacity from 0 to 1 but not 1 to 0. Idk if I should make a new question or just edit this one :/